# Heroku HTTP response code 200, should be 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, heroku, error-handling

I have a website I'm currently running on another web hosting service that I'm trying to move to heroku. I have a system for handling errors, which contains the following files:

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

DirectoryIndex /home.php

ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
ErrorDocument 503 /error.php
```

error.php:

```php
<?php
$httpc = http_response_code();
echo "Your http code is ".$httpc;
?>
```

So for example, if you visit a page that doesn't exist, it loads error.php and says "Your http code is 404". Only it doesn't, it says I have a 200 OK code. Though on the old host, it works just fine? Is there something different about how heroku handles errors or did I miss something?

Error Page: http://ankhsite.herokuapp.com/error.php

Testing the 404 error: http://ankhsite.herokuapp.com/thisdoesnotexist

**EDIT:** I also just realized this, but in the heroku logs I can even **visually see** it giving a 404 error.

[image: 404 error???????]

Comment: The manual states for http_response_code - `"If response_code is provided, then the previous status code will be returned. If response_code is not provided, then the current status code will be returned. Both of these values will default to a 200 status code if used in a web server environment."`

Comment: but why wouldn't it be using the previous code when it has one? I can even **visually see** in the heroku logs that it gives a 404 code when trying to view that page (edited it into the OP).